# Regarding subsequences - CLRS

Tags: algorithm, subsequence, clrs

I am reading chapter 15 from CLRS and came across this definition of a subsequence:

> A subsequence of a given sequence is just the given sequence with zero
>   or more elements left out.

Later it is said that:

> Each subsequence of X corresponds to a subset of the indices {1, 2,
>   3...m} of X. Because X has 2^m subsequences...

I don't see how `X` can have `2^m` subsequences. From what I understand, if 
 `X = {A, B}`, then the subsequences of `X` can be `{A}`, `{B}` and `{A, B}` so we have 3 subsequences and not `2^2`. Could someone please show me what I am missing here?

Comment: You're missing the empty subsequence -- the one with all the elements left out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one empty subset.

For any set S the power set of S is the number of subsets possible which is 2^|S| where |s| is the cardinality of the set, i.e number of elements in the set.

In your case the sequence is nothing but a set and the number of subsequence possible is equivalent to the power set of the sequence.

In your example X = {A, B} the possible sub sequences are {empty, A, B ,AB}